# no installed debugger has just in time debugging enabled error for malloc

Tags: c++, debugging, winapi

---

Hi guys,

I developing one Win32 application which collect some system data using some API.This application fine in all windows enviroment except XP.Gives me following error when i run it by double click.

[image]

But when i execute same exe using command prompt it will not show any thing.

Following line of code where this popup apeared,

```
FileContents = (char**)malloc( File_ArraSize * sizeof(char*) );     //allocating memory location..
```

Comment: Try to build and run a release version (i.e. not debug). Also on your XP box, have you done what it tells you to do? (i.e. have you enabled Just-In-Time debugging in VS?)

Comment: @rectummelancolique i already build executable in release mode . Why it working when i run it from command prompt??

Answer (score 0):

Download [Dependency Walker](http://dependencywalker.com/) onto the XP machine and open your program using Dependency Walker.  Once open, in the Profile menu select start profiling...

[image]

See what output this gives you.

---

Alternatively, you could install [WinDbg](http://windbg.org/) onto the XP machine and debug the application.

[Debuggers (x86)](http://www.windbg.org/X86%20Debuggers%20And%20Tools-x86_en-us.msi)

[Debuggers (x64)](http://www.windbg.org/X64%20Debuggers%20And%20Tools-x64_en-us.msi)